# How to close SAP pop-up windows with VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

I would have liked to have automated several extraction except that when I run the macro I have pop-up windows that annoy me terribly I can make them disappear by pressing enter.

```
  Public Sub RunGUIScript()

 Dim W_Ret As Boolean
 Dim Société As String
 Sheets("Extraction").Select
 Société = Range("b9")


   Application.SendKeys "{Enter}" 

 ' Connect to SAP
  W_Ret = Attach_Session
  If Not W_Ret Then
  Exit Sub
   End If


    On Error GoTo myerr



  objSess.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
  objSess.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "S_ALR_87012039"
  objSess.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
  objSess.findById("wnd[0]/usr/radSUMMB").Select
  objSess.findById("wnd[0]/usr/chkP_GRID").Selected = True
  [...]

  Exit Sub

  myerr:
  MsgBox "Error occured while retrieving data", vbCritical + vbOKOnly


  End Sub
```

The "Application.SendKeys "{Enter}" feature does not make my SAP windows disappear so it is not the solution that works

[image: Windows popup A script attempts connecting to SAP GUI]

[image: SAP popup No data was selected]

Comment: After which line do the pop-ups appear? You seem to have misplaced your `Application.SendKeys "{Enter}"`

Comment: @Nacorid Hello, It happens during the execution of the script it starts with (objSess...)

Comment: So, you get a pop-up after maximizing the SAP window? Or when attaching the session?

Comment: I have a window when I log in and at the end of the script telling me that I don't have any data (I would like to click on enter to be able to continue the script)

Comment: Can you be more specific? What window? The SAP window?

Comment: SAP windows, I put screenshots in my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first popup is SAP telling you, that a script is trying to access SAP. You can disable that information in the SAP settings.
Go to Options -> Accessibility & Scripting -> Scripting
And then remove the checkmark  from "Notify when a script attaches to SAP GUI" and "Notify when a script opens a connection"

[image]

The second popup can be closed with this line:

```
objSess.FindById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").Press
```

This will press the Ok button in the popup.

And if you want to know if the window did popup you can do that like this:

```
On Error Resume Next
objSess.FindById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").Press
If Err.Number = 0 Then
    'Button was pressed
End If
On Error GoTo 0
```

Put this piece of code after the line of code that causes the window to popup.